# Java: How to set a socket timeout with a "try with resources"

Tags: java, sockets, try-with-resources

I want to set a socket connection timeout. I know that I can set it using the connect method but this is my code:

```
try(Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(ip), port);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8")), true)){
```

Comment: What's the problem? Is it not giving the desired output? Is it throwing an error?

Comment: The problem is that I can't use getInputStream/getOutputStream until i connect the socket

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really clear from your question where you are stuck, but you can just keep using the `connect` method:

```
int timeout = 25000;
try (Socket socket = new Socket()) {
    socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("abc", 123), timeout);
    try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
         PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8")), true)) {

    }
}
```

Comment: How can I use getInputStream/getOutputStream if I still have to establish the connection?

Comment: Good point. Then you can nest two try-with-resources statements.

Comment: Thanks obviously it works. I should have thought more about this!

Answer (score 0):

```
try(Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(ip), port)) {
    socket.connect(adress, timeout);
} catch (Throwable t) {
    handleException(t);
}
```

Comment: The timeout you set is the connection timeout you can't set it after the connection .